# How to create a constructor in source file C++

Tags: c++

I have been researching for hours. This simple task is eluding me...

Any suggestions of refactoring are encouraged. I am not a C++ person obviously.

I've watched all these videos but none of the demo classes have multiple fields. I certainly have not seen a source file that initializes a null array.

Links:
[C++ - Classes - Creating Source files and Header files](https://youtu.be/plCegnf2h5g)

[Buckys C++ Programming Tutorials - 15 - Placing Classes in Separate Files](https://youtu.be/NTip15BHVZc)

[C++ Header Files*](https://youtu.be/9RJTQmK0YPI)

[How the C++ Linker Works](https://youtu.be/H4s55GgAg0I)

[Constructors in C++](https://youtu.be/FXhALMsHwEY)

[How to Write a C++ Class](https://youtu.be/3dHBFBw13E0)

[Separating a C++ class into a .h and .cpp files](https://youtu.be/gyA7uDlazkc)

**After a few comments I have updated the context of the question**

*Node.h*

```
#ifndef NODE_H_                                /* INCLUDE GUARD */
#define NODE_H_ 
#include <iostream>

namespace Node{
  class Node {
  private:                                       // PRIVATE FIELDS
    static const int size = 27;

  public:                                        // PUBLIC FIELDS
    Node(bool isWord);                           // CONSTRUCTOR

    bool isWord;
    Node* character[size]{};

    void insertme(std::string);                  // FUNCTION PROTOTYPE
    int  searchme(std::string);                  // FUNCTION PROTOTYPE
  };
}

#endif                                           // NODE_H_
```

*Node.cpp*

```
// SOURCE FILE

#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Node::Node(bool isWord) {
    /*
     * This constructor needs to:
     * set isWord to false
     * populate Node* character[size] to be filled with null
     */
};

void insertme(string token){
    return;
}

int searchme(string token){
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE**: this constructor does not throw any errors but it doesn't initialize the member fields the way I need it to

```
// SOURCE FILE

#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Node::Node(isWord) {};

void insertme(string token){
    return;
}

int searchme(string token){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just put `{}` at the end: `Node* character[size]{};`

Comment: @doug that initializes the array to be filled with null? Is that in the header file or source file?

Comment: @TedLyngmo isWord is supposed to be constructed as a null boolean

Comment: Truth. And I don't want to work through the macro abuse necessary to make null boolean a thing.

Comment: @Garrett Much clearer -  but the implementation is still `Node::Node(isWord) {};`. The _"null boolean"_ part is still a mystery though. What does that mean to you? Do you want `isWord` to be `false` by default? Something else?

Comment: @TedLyngmo `isWord` in the header file it is uninitialized. in the source file upon construction, it should be set to false.

Comment: You have the option to declare default values to function arguments in the declaration of the function. If you don't - you must supply arguments when calling the function.

Comment: @TedLyngmo ah, like Python. Could you please illustrate this? The exact syntax of C++ troubles me.

Comment: In your class definition you currently have `Node(bool isWord);`. Anyone wanting to use that constructor will have to supply an argument convertible to `bool`. Make it `Node(bool isWord = false);` and one could use it without arguments (in which case, `isWord` would be set to `false`). A definition of the function separate from the declaration should however _not_ have the default value in its signature.

Comment: @Garrett I tried to answer it in an actual answer instead. Trying to provide answes in comments isn't a good idea - I know that, but I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a default value for your constructor taking a `bool` if you want it to be usable *without* arguments. A constructor without any mandatory arguments is a *default* constructor.

The definition of the class and declaration of its member functions:

```
#pragma once // or a standard header guard

class Node {
public:
    Node(bool isWord = false); // this is now a default constructor

    // other members etc ...
};
```

A possible use of it:

```
#include "Node.h"              // where Node is defined

int main() {
    Node x;                    // default construct a `Node`
}
```

The definition of the constructor in `Node.cpp`:

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>

Node::Node(bool isWord) {      // note, no default values here
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isWord << '\n';
}
```

Output if compiled and linked:

```
false
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oPeWxYYh8)

Comment: if these were in separate files in a local directory. what is the command to compile the executable file? I'm receiving a linkage error on my mac: `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1`. when I ssh to a Linux server for that compiler (gcc 4.8.5) `main.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to Node::Node(bool) collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` This must be a user (me) error because it works as intended when all in a single file.

Comment: @Garrett You've now managed to _compile_ the code you asked about in the question. What you now see are _linker_ errors (a very different problem). The easy fix is to supply all your `.cpp` files to the compiler. `g++ -o program a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp` etc.

Comment: ah all of them. thank you. I will post a separate question if that issue persists. you answered this one very well.

Comment: it worked, you seriously made my day. sorry for the additional comments I know they're frowned upon on stack.

Comment: @Garrett No worries. I personally don't mind them at all (and I get mine removed regularly)

Answer (score 0):

In your header file, you've created a function prototype without a variable.

```
public:                                        // PUBLIC FIELDS
Node();                                      // CONSTRUCTOR
```

This will make the class use the default constructor which does nothing.

Instead, you need to define a constructor with a boolean parameter in the header file.

```
public:                                        // PUBLIC FIELDS
Node();                                      // CONSTRUCTOR
Node(bool);                                  // CONSTRUCTOR 2
```

You will also need to make sure you include the proper type in the function definition of the Node constructor in the .cpp file.

```
  Node::Node(bool isWord)  {
    // DO SOMETHING.
    };
```

Comment: what about the source file? in Node.h `Node(bool isWord);` and Node.cpp `Node::Node(state) {
    Node::isWord = state;
};`
I have errors in the source file.

Comment: in the parameter, bool has an error of: `expected an identifier` when setting `isWord` the error reads:`'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member function`. for has an error with`expected a declaration`

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do?